# /mlmodels/Inceptionv3.mlmodel: unable to read document

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got this message error:

```
Inceptionv3.mlmodel: unable to read document
```

[image]

I downloaded the last version of xcode. `Version 9.4 beta (9Q1004a)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the Inception3.mlmodel file. You must get it. Next, drag and drop it to the project. Then you can remove this red file shortcut you already have.

The main problem is to get that file. All pages send you to 
https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/
but Apple doesn't show download, wich previous probably looks like that:

https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*6agZ1CcGVwiOaX3gNP8cYw.png

I had the same problem with GoogLeNetPlaces. I found some models on
 https://github.com/SwiftBrain/awesome-CoreML-models
but to find the file that interested me most I used torrent.